# After I login with email and password, I need to pass my email to the further page for retrieve the user data from the API. (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication

as the title stated above, after login, I need to pass user email to the further page (home page) so the user detail will be shown out automatically, the backend api of user detail wil receive the email from frontend.  The code are as below:

I'm new in react, hope anyone can guide me for this. Great Appreciate.

This is my login.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import {PostData} from '../../services/PostData';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {

constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    loginEmail: '',
    loginPassword: '',
    redirect: false
  }
  this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

login(){
  if(this.state.loginEmail && this.state.loginPassword){
    PostData('api/users/login', this.state).then ((result) => {
      let responseJSON = result;
      console.log(responseJSON)
      if(responseJSON.user){
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', responseJSON);
        // console.log("Home Page")
        this.setState({redirect: true});
      }else{
        console.log("Login Error")
        alert("wrong user credential")
      }
    });
  }
}

onChange(e){
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

  render(){

    if(this.state.redirect){
      return (<Redirect to ={'/home'}/>)
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("user")){
      return (<Redirect to ={'/home'}/>)
    }

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column bodyPart">
          <h3>Login</h3>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="loginEmail" placeholder= "email" onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" className="button" onClick={this.login}/>
            <a href="/SignUp">Registration</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

after login successfully, it will come to home page, but at the same time, an user detail api will also been call to retrieve the data.

This is homepage.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    redirect: false
  }
  this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("user")){
    console.log("Call User Feed");
  }else{
    this.setState({redirect: true});
  }
}

logout(){
  sessionStorage.setItem("user", '');
  sessionStorage.clear();
  this.setState({redirect: true});
}

  render(){

    if(this.state.redirect){
      return (<Redirect to ={'/login'}/>)
    }

    return (
      <div className="callout primary" id="Home">
        <div className="row column">
          <h1> Hi, Home </h1>
          <button type='button' className="button" onClick={this.logout}>logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The api of user detail 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could either add the user e-mail as a query parameter to your redirect, use redux to create a global store for all your components, or save the email in the browsers local storage.

Personally I would use the redux method. It is a bit complex at the beginning but if your application gets bigger it is easier to move data through your application.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I get from many advice that redux quite tough for beginner right? and if there is no guider or expertise of react redux will be difficult to exploring more .

Comment: In my opinion it is worth the time. At first you can use redux as a event dispatcher with an own state. You can get some quick dive in here: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start
However, you can use the local storage or the query parameter as well (you already use the session storage, so you can go with that).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your user in the state of your Login component, you should be able to pass them down to the Home component as props using Redirect:

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/home',
    state: { loginEmail : this.state.loginEmail }}}/>
```

And in the child, you'll access it with `this.props.location.state.loginEmail`

That being said, I'll join my voice with others in this thread to advocate for Redux if you need this at multiple levels of your application. There's a bit of a learning curve, but if you need to access information that belongs to the *application* moreso than any individual component, it's a convenient place to store it and an reliable place to retrieve it from.

In the meantime, if you'd like to do some further investigating about how / why to pass information with `react-router` I'd suggest starting [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object)!